# Trouble installing ggplot2 because of 'scales'

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation

I am getting the below message after trying to install ggplot2 using

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): there is no package called ‘scales’

Comment: Run `install.packages("scales")`

Comment: Should have used `install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)` to install all dependencies for `ggplot2`